# How to stub out the controllers called by express routes when unit testing routes

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, express, sinon, proxyquire

I am trying to unit test express routes such as the following:

```
var app = express();
app.get('/',indexController.Index);
```

In my unit tests I am using code such as the following:

```
const indexController = {};
indexController.Index = sinon.stub();
const server = proxyquire('../server.js', { './controllers/indexController': indexController }); 
describe('GET /', () => {
  it('index controller should be called', (done) => {
    request(server)
      .get('/')
      .expect(200)
      .end((err, res) => {
        if (err) {
          return done(err);
        }
        sinon.assert.called(indexController.Index);
        return done();
      });
  });
});
```

As you can see what I want to do is to stub the controller out. But this does not seem to be working (original controller seems to be called instead of the stub). And I can not figure out why. (The same approach worked when doing unit tests on the controllers and the models.)

Can some explain why this is not working. And any alternative way to testing these routers.

Comment: Can you share your server.js and controller.js code as well?

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62626143/why-is-my-sinon-stub-acting-like-its-calling-the-real-function